# Does every integer $n > 2$ have a "reciprocating" pseudoprime $a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does every integer $n > 2$ have a "reciprocating" pseudoprime $a$ such that $\gcd(a, n) = 1$ and satisfies both $a^{n - 1} \equiv 1 \mod n$ and $n^{a - 1} \equiv 1 \mod a$? (And of course allowing for the idea of even pseudoprimes).

From Fermat's little theorem it follows all odd primes have such a corresponding number.

Comment: Do you consider it valid if for a composite $n$ if the "reciprocating pseudoprime" is actually prime? For example, $5^3 \equiv 1 \mod 4$, and $4^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$.

Comment: Yes, I do. Maybe the question is more interesting if we require the reciprocating pseudoprime to be composite, but maybe it's more provable if we don't.

Comment: If you allow $a$ to be prime, we can just take any prime $a\equiv1\pmod n$.

Comment: I suspect the question may be interesting but unprovable if we require composites to "reciprocate" to composites, and provable but trivial if we don't.

Comment: By perusing http://oeis.org/wiki/Table_of_Fermat_pseudoprimes I get: 4, 85; 6???; 8, 9; 10, 91; 12???; 14, 15; 16???; 18???; 20, 21; I haven't looked farther out than that.

Comment: Thank you, @Lisa. For 6, one has to go a little farther, to 217. For 12, there's 133. Haven't found one for 16 yet.

Answer (score 6):

For any composite $n$, take $a = \dfrac{n^n - 1}{n - 1}$. It is easy to prove that $a$ is also composite and $(a, n) = 1$. Note that$$
a = \frac{n^n - 1}{n - 1} = n^{n - 1} + \cdots + n + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \Longrightarrow a^{n - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}.
$$
Also,$$
n^n = (n - 1)a + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{a} \Longrightarrow n^{a - 1} = (n^n)^{\frac{n^{n - 1} - 1}{n - 1}} \equiv 1 \pmod{a}.
$$
Thus $a = \dfrac{n^n - 1}{n - 1}$ satisfies given conditions.